# some DateFormat AM/PM formatting options don't appear to be working on AVD for API Level 8

Tags: android, android-emulator, date-format, android-2.2-froyo

[android.text.format.DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html) specifies that using the format string 'a' should yield 'a' or 'p' and 'aa' should yield 'am' or 'pm'. However, on my AVD, using 'a', 'A', or 'AA' yields 'am' or 'pm' which is not congruent with the on-line documentation.

```
final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

Log.i("DateFormat", "a: " + (String) DateFormat.format("a", currentTimeMillis));
Log.i("DateFormat", "aa: " + (String) DateFormat.format("aa", currentTimeMillis));
Log.i("DateFormat", "A: " + (String) DateFormat.format("A", currentTimeMillis));
Log.i("DateFormat", "AA: " + (String) DateFormat.format("AA", currentTimeMillis));
```

Since DateFormat has been available since API Level 3, am I running into a regression or is there something wrong with my development environment? (I'm new to android so I don't have much experience with this framework yet). AVD is configured for API Level 8 and I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got around to looking at the source code and as far as I can tell, these formatting options were never implemented correctly. Only 2 possible localized strings are retrieved and they are not manipulated any further, which is what I'm observing.

I've filed a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16997

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SimpleDateFormat as explained on [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("a hh-mm-ss");
date = new Date();
sDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer resolves my observed issues since java.text.SimpleDateFormat does not support am/pm formats besides all uppercase and thus only addresses 1 of 4 the cases I presented, albeit a case that doesn't seem to be working with android.text.format.DateFormat.